# Python, PHP and Wordpress: Discrepancies between XAMPP, SiteGound SSH, and Wordpress Output

Tags: python, php, wordpress

I'm scratching my head after seeing different output with this framework across multiple machines. I am attempting to run a python script from within a PHP file and print the results from the python file. Ultimately I want to display the results in a wordpress site via a plugin. I have the following files:

helloworld.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("hello world!")
```

py_embed.php

```
<?php
exec("python helloworld.py", $output);
var_dump($output);
?>
```

When I run py_embed.php on my own windows machine I see the expected output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "hello world!"
```

I can also open py_embed.php using an Apache server from XAMPP by going to localhost//py_embed.php and I again see the expected output.

Finally, I can check the results when I run py_embed.php from my SiteGround-hosted web server. I can SSH into the SiteGround server and I again see the expected results.

Now, I can integrate the php script into a WordPress plugin by creating a new php file:

php_python_together.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: php-python-together
 * Plugin URI: ....
 * ....
 */

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'func_php_py' );

function func_php_py() {
    exec("python helloworld.py", $output);
    var_dump($output);
}

?>
```

After activating the wordpress plugin I see the following unexpected output in the wordpress page's footer:

```
array(0) { }
```

This tells me that the call to helloworld.py didn't success since $output returned as an empty array. I do have helloworld.py and php_python_together.php in the same folder location. I did that via FTP. How do I even go about troubleshooting this? The framework works on local, XAMPP, SiteGround's server, but breaks when I convert to a wordpress plugin. Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: php-python-together
 * Plugin URI: ....
 * ....
 */

function func_php_py() {
    echo shell_exec("python helloworld.py");
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'func_php_py' );
```

Note: This code requires that your Python script is in same folder as your Plugin.

This might not be safe, I will recommend to put this python script elsewhere, not in web server folders. If you do so then add Full Path to this python file.

Example: If your WordPress ROOT folder is: `/var/www/`

Then create a folder like: `/var/safe/` and save your python script there.

And in your functions.php file add full path like:

```
function func_php_py() {
    echo shell_exec("python /var/safe/helloworld.py");
}
```

If this still dosent work then add full path to Python as well:

```
function func_php_py() {
    echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /var/safe/helloworld.py");
}
```

Comment: Hey Cyborg, thanks for taking a look. That didn't do it for me. In fact, that didn't return anything to the wordpress footer. I need to have an echo in there in order to print to the footer. For example, echo "this is my footer"; correctly displays the text. However, when I use the $output from executing python it's still an empty Array. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. For some reason my working directory within wordpress was not the location of the php-python-together.php plugin. I expected the working directory to be ~/public_html/wp-content/plugins/php-python-together. That's where my plugin file and helloworld.py were both located. The directory that wordpress defaulted to was simply ~/public_html. So, by changing the directory in my php-python-together.php file it worked!

Two php functions that helped me immensely were:

```
echo getcwd();
chdir();
```

Good luck to all!